# Netbeans editor behavior in new line

Tags: netbeans, coding-style, development-environment

In Netbeans 8.0.1 when I start coding with

```
$variable = '';
```

and put cursor between single quotes and next press Enter key then the editor doing something like this:

```
$variable = ''
        . '';
```

Where can I switch off this functionality to behavior like this:

```
$variable = '
';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer by myself: It is option after update from 8.0.0 to 8.0.1 in:
 Tools-> Options -> Code Completion - > PHP -> Use String Auto-Concatenation after Typed Break.